# Efficiently computing date/time stamp for logging purposes on unix/win32

Tags: c++, winapi, unix, logging, timestamp

I'm in a situation where after having profiled and analyzed our system, come to the conclusion that the logging component of the system is one of the many bottle necks taking up about ~17% of total running time - a lot of things are logged.

Of this, about 5% of the time the logger consumes is related to producing a date/time stamp in ascii in the following format: YYYYMMDD HHMMSS.fff - we roughly log about 700k lines per second. (roughly 700K x (localtime and gettimeofday) calls per second)

I was wondering what techniques fellow SOers have for producing time-stamps efficiently.

Cross platform solutions would be welcomed.

Note1: we looked into Boost.datetime - it's great, but a bit too slow for our needs, std::chrono is a perfect solution, however we unfortunately  have to support pre c++11 compilers.

Note2: We've implemented a simple optimisation that only computes the date part (yyyymmdd) one per 24hrs hence only having 1 gettimeofday call per line - didn't help much though.

Comment: Does the *formatting* that take up 5% alone, or does that include the other calls to fetch the time? (Although, even if the 5% were turned to 0% it'd still be like ~16.7% total :-)

Comment: @pst: this is just the calls to populate the various time structs. the formatting (converting to ascii) is another issue altogether.

Comment: @pst: but any ideas for doing the formatting would be great, we already use luts of ascii combos to speed out the process eg: 01020304050607080910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031  anything like this in mind?

Comment: Are you willing to post-process your logs?

Comment: @PuraVida: No - I know where you're going, log sequence numbers instead and every 100ms or so log a time stamp then evenly extrapolate out times between time intervals and the sequence numbers inbetween those times. The problem with this is that things may occurs/cluster at the start of the time bucket and then nothing else after it. doesn't work well in real-life.

Comment: Well, my next question is whether you are running on x86 or some other processor with a constant timestamp counter... on recent x86 processors from Intel & AMD the RDTSC instruction will return a 64 bit counter that increments at a constant rate... it takes roughly 22 processor cycles to read it (7 nanoseconds).  You can log that value and periodically also log gettimeofday, then interpolate the middle times, like you said.  Linux uses that same counter to implement gettimeofday.

Comment: Are you caching the formatted result? (ie if the millisecond hasn't changed then use the previous result).  I'd also ask the obvious question - do you *really* need to be logging 700K times per second?

Comment: Log the raw unformatted time (e.g. time_t) and do the asctime conversion offline.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of using C++11, you should check out [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Failing that, the optimisation would depend on the resolution you need. 
I would ask if you absolutely need timestamps on the logging or if occassional timestamps with sequence information might be useful?

Example:

```
<timestamp1> <seq_num_0> ...
<timestamp1> <seq_num_1> ...
....
<timestamp1> <seq_num_n-1> ...
<timestamp2> <seq_num_0> ...
```

The way I see it, you have two problems:

1. Synchronizing the timestamps with other systems
2. Getting an accurate timestamp on a single system

I would use a timer based system to update the timestamp **twice** every millisecond and re-use it between updates. I would then make sure that the systems your code runs on have their clocks synchronized to an atomic clock. You generate the timestamp twice to try and compensate for the flakiness of the underlying OS's timer mechanisms.

I don't think you could get much better than that.

EDIT: Actually, you can. Make sure you only format the timestamp string when it changes. You also don't need a sequence number, if you can guarantee that entries get logged in the order they come in. Given those two assumptions, your logging problem now reduces to how fast you can concatenate and write out two strings.

UPDATE 2: If BOOST isn't suitable and if you can't use C++11, it boils down to this:

1. Use a timer to set and format the timestamp twice every millisecond - you can do this via OS level APIs.
2. Make sure that events are logged in the order they come in.

Assuming I/O isn't your bottleneck, your problem is then nothing but one of fast string concatenation.

Comment: Time-stamps are critical as we use them to matchup events occuring on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd delay any and all formatting until actually needed:

```
struct log_entry {
    struct timeval timestamp;
    unsigned int code;
    union {
        struct param1 p1;
        struct param2 p2;
    };
};
```

The `paramN` structures contain the data appropriate for the event in whatever form they were in at that time, but as a copy (so the log data can be analyzed standalone).

Depending on your requirements, you can keep this data in a ring buffer and either constantly overwrite old data, or dump it to disk when a certain percentage is reached.

Comment: +1 - that's basically what I would do given the OP's nasty requirement for logging-rate.  Create an array of 1M of these things to act as a circular buffer and then every, say 100ms, issue start/end indexes to the logger thread, perhaps with the wall-time too if the timestamp member contains only tick-counts, (or whatever is returned by the fastest time-related API on whatever OS).  The logger thread can do formatting, adding offsets to wall-time, interpolating etc. in nice, big chunks.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** Multiple downvoters now. Please leave a comment, so I can address the issues properly. Thanks!

You could reorganize your code so that your logger is reading a date timestamp string from a buffer that is updated N times a second (depending on your desired resolution) by some other thread. For 4 times a second:

```
struct current_time_stamp {
    char timestr_[4][16];
    unsigned index_;
    unsigned subsecond_;
    const char *get () const { return timestr_[index_%4]; }
    void update () {
        // ... update string in timestr_[(index_+1)%4] ...
        // ... if (index_ + 1)%4 is zero, recompute subsecond_
        ATOMIC_INCREMENT(index_);
        // ... also need a memory barrier for timestr_ update
    }
};
```

The sub-second resolution for each log would read from a high performance counter. DeadMG suggests `QueryPerformanceTimer` on windows, and on Linux (and POSIX) there is `clock_gettime`. If, however, the overhad of those implementations is still to high for you, you can query the time stamp counter on the processor directly using inline assembly (see `rdtsc` for x86). The subsecond value is delta'd from the one recorded in the structure to get the proper offset.

If you can get away with logging the time stamp in a binary format, that would get away from the formatting issue.

Comment: Why would you not simply use a regular high-performance counter, like `QueryPerformanceCounter`? There's no reason to go down to inline assembler here.

Comment: @DeadMG: The question was about performance. I have no experience using `QueryPerformanceCounter` on windows, but using `rdtsc` directly on Linux beat direct calls to `clock_gettime` by 100x.

Comment: Is completely specific to your implementation, your compiler, and your circumstances. You would need profile data to prove this for the OP.

Comment: OP said he was calling `gettimeofday` 700K times per second. My solution reduces that to some number much smaller than that, but still needs an efficient way to extract the subsecond resolution. I offered a suggestion that should be faster than `gettimeofday`. Do you think my suggestion would be slower?

Comment: @DeadMG: Please let me know what else about the answer you think is wrong. Thanks, and regards